# Max Length - Unit Quantities

Tags: python, geometry, packing

Let say I have made a program to detect how many beds I should put in a room. 
If I have the max length and width of the room, and the max length and width of each bed, I want to print how many beds its possible on the x and y direction. is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem.  You should also read [ask].

Comment: If the room and beds are non rectangular, this very quickly becomes extremely complex. If they are then this is pretty simple.

Comment: The rooms are rectangulars